# jquery.post and variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and have the following problem.
I want to load some json from an api.php and succeed with the returned value to fill my GUI.

```
    $( '#data_button' ).click(function() {
    $.post( 'api.php', function( data ) { json = data; });
    $('#data1').empty().append( json[0].name + ' | ' + json[1].name );
});
```

So I wanna click a button, then it fetches via post some data ans save this to the variable data.
As it should be an object (json object?) I thought I just can use it as above...
But that doesn't work. Console say: can't find variable json.

Any hints?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with scope, only with timing. Please have a look at [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I'd suggest you to read about asynchronous programming and  JavaScript's function scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery post as default works asynchronously which means that the line:

```
$('#data1').empty().append( json[0].name + ' | ' + json[1].name );
```

occur before the post request have returned the data.

this how it should be done:

```
$( '#data_button' ).click(function() {
     $.post( 'api.php', function( data ) { 
         $('#data1').empty().append( data[0].name + ' | ' + data[1].name );
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you! It was just too late... and too obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You have your appending outside the post callback function. Try this:

```
$( '#data_button' ).click(function() {
    $.post( 'api.php', function( data ) { 
        json = data; 
        $('#data1').empty().append( json[0].name + ' | ' + json[1].name );
     });
});
```